# Teradata SQL 3 variables into two variable based on conditions

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a table with 3 different phone numbers in it and I want to reduce it down to two phone numbers based on if the number is a mobile or landline.

The table is in the format as follows:

[image: Sample Data with Output (Phone1 & Phone2)]

```
CASE WHEN TR1.PHONE_TYPE = 'M' THEN 'SOURCE_FULL_MOBILE_NO'
     WHEN TR1.PHONE_TYPE <> 'M' AND TR2.PHONE_TYPE = 'M' THEN 'SOURCE_DAYTIME_NUMBER'
     WHEN TR3.PHONE_TYPE = 'M' AND TR1.PHONE_TYPE <> 'M' AND TR2.PHONE_TYPE <> 'M' THEN 'SOURCE_EVENING_NUMBER'
     WHEN TR1.PHONE_TYPE = 'L' AND TR2.PHONE_TYPE <> 'M' AND TR3.PHONE_TYPE <> 'M' THEN 'SOURCE_FULL_MOBILE_NUMBER'
     WHEN TR2.PHONE_TYPE = 'L' AND TR1.PHONE_TYPE <> 'M' AND TR3.PHONE_TYPE <> 'M' THEN 'SOURCE_DAYTIME_NUMBER'
     WHEN TR3.PHONE_TYPE = 'L' AND (TR1.PHONE_TYPE <> 'M'  OR TR1.PHONE_TYPE IS NULL ) AND (TR2.PHONE_TYPE <> 'M' OR TR2.PHONE_TYPE IS NULL ) THEN  'SOURCE_EVENING_NUMBER'
     else null
END as Phone1
```

The issue is I believe I should be able to program this using a logic table... However, when I run the section above, if Mobile is null and Evening number is null and Daytime is populated both phone1 and phone2 are null. However, phone 1 should be populated with daytime phone number. 
Is there something I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: "I have a table with 3 different phone numbers ".  Your code references three table aliases.  Which is it?  One table or three?

Comment: And how do the CASE-conditions match the example data?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. The code is a snippet from a larger table that is made up of contact details. On the original table there is MOBILE_AREA_CDE, MOBILE_NO, DAYTIME_AREA_CDE, DAYTIME_NO and the same for evening. FULL_MOBILE_NO is a concatenation of MOBILE_AREA_CDE & MOBILE_NO.